# Can one XML schema enumeration extend another?

Tags: xsd, enumeration, extend

I'd like my XML schema to contain two string enumerations, one that extends the other:

- Enumeration 1: dog, cat
- Enumeration 2 (adds "snake" to the first): dog, cat, snake

I've tried a [union](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-extenum/#solution2), but the resulting type doesn't seem to be an enumeration, at least it's not recognised by [xAmple](http://www.felixgolubov.com/XMLEditor/) as such.

Is there a way to have one enumeration extend another and still be an enumeration?

Answer (score 1):

Simple types can only be derived by restriction and not by extension. (Unions are special and considered to be restrictions of `anySimpleType`.)

If you're just trying to avoid duplication (rather than define a hierarchy) then union should be fine for validation, though it's not surprising that some tools won't look into the union to do something smart.

Another option is to define a base type will all values (dog, cat, snake) and then derive a class that only contains the subset. That gives you a hierarchy but the derived class must either repeat the subset (dog, cat) or disallow the others (snake) by regex. (And using the regex will probably also trip up many editors.)

Comment: Sadly, using a regex to exclude members of an enumeration doesn't work in the XML editors I tried (Eclipse and xAmple).